# Multiple negative constraints do not work in JAPE

Tags: nlp, gate

I am trying to develop jape rules to classify text based on the previously created tags on it.

Then I create these rules:

```
//Prediction A
Rule: A_Predictor
(
    {RECORD contains {Indicator.rule == A}}
): predict_A
-->
:predict_A.Prediction = {prediction = A}


//Prediction B
Rule: B_Predictor
(
    {RECORD contains {Indicator.rule == B}, !RECORD contains {Indicator.rule == A}}
): predict_B
-->
:predict_B.Prediction = {prediction = B}

//Prediction C
Rule: C_Predictor
(
    {RECORD contains {Indicator.rule == C}, !RECORD contains {Indicator.rule == A}, !RECORD contains {Indicator.rule == B}}
): predict_C
-->
:predict_C.Prediction = {prediction = C}
```

As you can see that I have multiple conditions to match for each `prediction`, especially to predict B and C. But, these rules still give prediction `B` even though there are `Indicator.rule == a` in the `RECORD`, which I assume that I have already negate it in the rule above.

What's wrong with my code?

Any helps will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried "notContains"?

As in:

```
Rule: B_Predictor
(
    {RECORD contains {Indicator.rule == B}, RECORD notContains {Indicator.rule == A}}
): predict_B
-->
:predict_B.Prediction = {prediction = B}
```

I think the ! negates the whole statement and "!RECORD contains indicator A" will match anything that is not a RECORD which contains indicator A (for instance a Token or RECORD which contains indicator B).

With notContains you also know that it's the same RECORD annotation in the two statements.